# Question regarding the p-valuation of an integer

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. The p-adic order or p-adic valuation for $\mathbb{Z}$ is defined as $\nu_p : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\nu_p(n) =\begin{cases}
\max\{v \in \mathbb{N} : p^{v}|n \} & \text{if } n \neq 0\\
\infty & \text{if } n=0\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Now, consider $S$ to be a set of uniformly distributed random integers. Then we have
$$ \nu_p(S) = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + \dots = \frac{1}{p-1}$$

I have been trying to figure this out for a while, but I don't how ? Am I missing something obvious here? Any hints would be welcome !

Comment: How exactly are you choosing these "uniformly distributed random integers"? And what is meant by the $p$-adic valuation of a set?

Comment: $\nu_p(S) = \nu_p(s)$ for $s \in S$ and $S$ is not defined more specifically, it is just a set of random integers.

Comment: Makes no sense. $\nu_p(s)$ must be an integer.

Comment: @Sasha Perhaps you mean $\;v_p(S)\;$ to be the sum, or the mean or something of *all* the valuations $\;v_p(s)\;,\;\;s\in S\;$ ? Otherwise is hard to understand what you mean by $\;v_p(S)\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that $\nu_p(S)$ is intended to be the expected $p$-adic valuation of a member of $S$ chosen at random with uniform probability. I’m no probabilist, but the reasoning must be something along the following lines.

Say $S$ is finite, of cardinality $n$. For $k\ge 1$ you expect about $\frac{n}{p^k}$ members of $S$ to be divisible by $p^k$. If $s\in S$ and $\nu_p(s)=m$, $s$ is divisible by $p^k$ for $k=1,\ldots,m$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{s\in S}\nu_p(s)&=\sum_{s\in S}\sum_{k=1}^{\nu_p(s)}1\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\sum_{s\in S}\left[p^k\mid s\right]\\
&\approx\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{n}{p^k}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the expected $p$-adic valuation of a randomly chosen member of $S$ is therefore approximately

$$\frac1n\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{n}{p^k}=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{p^k}=\frac1{p-1}\;.$$

(Here $\left[p^k\mid s\right]$ is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).)

Comment: thanks ! it seems to make sense

Comment: @Sasha: You’re welcome!